# Magento 2.1 REST API configurableProductLinkManagementV1 only adds first simple product to configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, api, magento-2.1, rest-api, simple-product

I'm making a call to REST API configurableProductLinkManagementV1. The first simple product is associated correctly. Any simple product after that is not. The error I receive states "option values are not specified". I'm passing in the following JSON:

'{"childSKU": "my SKU here"}'

I'm running Magento 2.1.0, PHP version 5.6.25-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Apache/2.4.7, Ubuntu Linux 14.04, MySQL 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.

Only the first simple product has been added to the configurable product.  No other simple products get added.

What are the correct steps when creating simple/configurable products and associating the products to one another? And is there any where that I can find what the different REST API JSON objects represent? The REST API documentation doesn't give enough detailed information.